# Запись pdf файла в QByteArray

Tags: qt, qt5, pdf

Как записать pdf файл в QByteArray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Get PDF", QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation), tr("Pdf (*.pdf)"));

QFile file(fileName); 

if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;

QByteArray byteArray = file.readAll();
```